# Google Maps Transparant tile on Internet Explorer in GWT Dialogue Box

Tags: internet-explorer, google-maps, gwt, css

I am using googlemaps inside a GWT Dialogbox. I applied following css to the dialogbox

```
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
      -moz-box-shadow:    4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
      box-shadow:         4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);  
       -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=5, Direction=135, Color='#736F6E')";
      /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
      filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=5, Direction=135, Color='#736F6E');
```

to add shadow effect to the dialogue box. The code works fine on FF, Chrome but on IE it creates transparent tile (hole) on zoom for the infowindow. I tried to use Z-Index  css property on the dialogbox  to keep it up but I still get the error.
Is there any way to avoid the transparent tile in google maps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY THIS

http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/